# Task.Delay creating System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object' with SignalR group

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am writing a code with asp.net core and Signalr, where have a method:

```
public async void newGameTimer(int tableID )
        {
            bool stop = true;
            int val = 0;
            while (stop)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                val++;
                if (val > 5)
                {
                    stop = false;
                    newGame(tableID);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then in newGame(tableID) method, which is as below:

```
public async void newGame(int tableID)
{
    await Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("updateTotalPot", 200);
}
```

I am sending asyn response to group of player through signalR Group. but it's giving error

'System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name'

I did search and got answered like 'Task.Dealy()' can create ObjectDisposed error.
Now can't understand, how to solve the problem.

I only want to wait for some-time and then send response to group of players.. Is anyone can help me?

Project: Online real-time Poker game
Poker online game, where a group of friends can create a table and play Poker togahter.
Frontend: React
Backend: asn.net core, Signalr, Redis

Logic:
First player create table by calling the method:

```
public async Task LoginWindow(string name, string password, int newTable, int joinTable)
{ 
   //- this method saves many keys in Redis in-memory like this
    dbr.StringSet("table" + "ToBet", 0);

  //- at end send reply with following command
     await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("updateMessage",  "Welcome to table no " + tableID);

//- then this method check, if second player has called this method, then calls the timer to start game after 5 seconds

  newGameTimer(tableID);
 
}


nothing else...
```

Comment: Before -ve voting, please let me know, why I deserve for -ve vote, because I'm trying to solve to problem for many hours, but couldn't do that..

Comment: Do you have a Stack Trace for the exception? Next question: why `async void` not `async Task`? If that is by design and not a kind of bad practice, where's exception handling?

Comment: Actually,  'async Task' was creating the same error, like it 'Disposed' the object automatically. so I set void, which solve the issue, but now 'Task.delay()' giving the same error..

Comment: Actully, 'await Task.delay()' creating problem, because if I remove the line, then it works fine and send response properly..

Comment: In short, the problem is outside of the shown code. Please show that method where do you call `newGameTimer()` and then I will answer the question with the fixed code. You can Edit the question.

Comment: I edit question, which contains newGameTimer()'s caller method. There is nothing, except than saving data in Redix, and sending response to caller player, and at end, calling newGameTimer()..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `async void` here. The solution may look like this.

```csharp
public async Task NewGameWithDelay(int tableID)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (await CheckForSecondPlayer())
        {
            // found
            await Clients.Group(group).SendAsync("updateTotalPot", 200);
            return;
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    // not found
}

private async Task<bool> CheckForSecondPlayer()
{
    // if found return true, else
    return false;
}
```

```csharp
public async Task LoginWindow(string name, string password, int newTable, int joinTable)
{ 
    dbr.StringSet("table" + "ToBet", 0);
    await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("updateMessage",  "Welcome to table no " + tableID);
    await NewGameWithDelay(tableID);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, but it didn't help me, and gave me same error 'ObjectDisposed'   and actully I can't delay directly 5 second, because I have to check evey second, if there is any new player.. please tell me one thins, Is there any other way, to have async waite, so I can avoid Task.delay().

Comment: I'll start new attempt tomorrow again with fresh mind because it's 2am here now.. I'll update you dear.. BTW, thanks for your precious time.